# Strategy to ask app-users for review

Tags: mobile, android, ios, ratings, user-feedback

I am a Front-end developer in a team and we are developing a travel app for Android and IOS. This mobile app offers users to search and book hotels. 
**We want to build a mechanism to ask users for rating the app after booking process.**

We have a set of criteria regarding firing a popup window to ask for a review:

- A popup should appear with content like "Thank you for using XX-App. Please help us to improve our services by rating us on App Store/Google Play".
- Popup should have three buttons with actions like "Rate now", "Remind me later", "No, thanks"
- Popup should appear after first booking process.
- If user taps on "Rate now", the popup won't be shown again later
- It should be as easy as possible: There is no special page or form to ask for feedback, but rather user will be redirected to app-page from App Store/Google Play.

**The key questions are**

- If user taps on "Remind me later", should the popup appear again after second booking process or is it ok show it after a defined time independent if user completed another booking process or not.
- If user taps on "No, thanks", should popup appear again after second booking process?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say if they click `Remind me later`, it pops up after the next booking, and if the press `No, thanks` it wouldn't popup again. As a user that's how I'd expect it to work. Popups after just an interval don't make sense to me, I'd rather be asked after I complete an action, that would urge me to leave a review more than a random popup

Comment: I'd just show it once. If they're not inclined to review the app the first time, you'll just annoy them by repeatedly asking. Maybe create an analogy to understand the flow better: You go to the supermarket and someone stops you on the way out, post-checkout,  and asks you to do a survey - you politely decline. Again you go to the supermarket, again they ask you. This continues. How do you feel about the supermarket as time goes on and the same person asks you about the survey?

Comment: One thing to add. Based on the options provided, if the user taps on "No, Thanks" it should NOT appear again. Usually if you give the users a choice, no means no. By showing the popup again, you are just defying the user expectation that the popup is gone for good.

Comment: Why we always ask users to rate our app? Why not we ask them other questions for feedback? I would prefer to directly ask my user for questions and reply to them directly.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing many other apps I have noticed that they tend to ask you to rate the app right  when the app **opens** or when it **closes**. It is refreshing to see this idea of waiting for them to book a trip with your app as it shows they are using the app successfully, this shows that they will be more inclined to rate the app then someone starting it for the 1st or 2nd time. That being said I think that if you are going to give an option for **"No Thanks"** then it appears later I personally feel that it is kind of a pointless option. The **"Remind Me Later"** option should be the option that then appears after they make another booking with your app. If you don't want to enable the user to turn off the "Rate Me" pop-up then don't offer them a **"No Thanks"** option and stick simply with **"Remind Me Later"** or **"Rate Now"**. Hope this helps.

Comment: No "No thanks" option would have uninstall the app immediately. And that's when I am feeling nice.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the "review me" question appear in the notification area on Android apps.  I liked how unobtrusive this was, letting me view it at my own pace.  Notifications have the ability to have buttons attached to them now, so you could have a "Review!" and "Remind me later" and "Dismiss" button made available.  You never want to annoy your users such that they get frustrated with your app.  I would set a max limit of "Remind Me's" to 2-3.

(Disclaimer, I also make reservation related apps)

In the context of your app, after a booking is made, you could have a notice appear saying "Thanks for the reservation!  Please let us know what you think of us!"  with some options below.

Answer (score 0):

If they say Remind Me Later a good strategy is to ask for a review at the next positive engagement such as successfully checking out/purchase of an item.

Answer (score -1):

If the user answers "No, thanks", I will not show the dialog and ask again. As from the user's point of view, he already refused to rate the app.

Comment: What about if they've clicked 'Remind me Later'?